# What is the UNC network path to a folder shared via Samba?

Tags: samba, shared-folders

I am trying to direct a scanner to scan directly to a shared folder on my home network. The scanner's web service asks for the network path to my shared folder, and only accepts UNC as input, i. e. `\\server\volume\path`.  My share is at `//home/<user>/Public` on a particular computer on my network.  I know the IP address and netbios name of the computer, and know the shared folder path on my Ubuntu machine, but don't know how to plug that in to come up with a valid UNC path to my shared folder.

UPDATE:  This is not a duplicate of the question that asked how to navigate to a samba share via command line of a share created in Nautilus.  Instead, I was asking how to direct a web server to my samba share when the web server uses a Windows (UNC) input mask.  I already knew the path to my samba share from the terminal and from other Linux devices on the network.  I didn't know how samba characterized this path to Windows machines or web servers that assume the Windows UNC file path naming conventions.

Comment: If it's a duplicate, I'm not sure how to interpret the answer there.  I have tried "smb:\\192.168.1.[xxx]\home\[user]\Public" and just "\\192.168.1.[xxx]\home\[user]\Public" as the Network path.  Anything with "smb:" is rejected as an invalid path by the input mask.  Any other path I put in is rejected also, with the message "invalid shared folder...check the network path and try again."

Comment: On Linux you should use `//`.  My idea was to determine full share name from Nautilus - for example `smb://host_name_or_ip/share_name` to write then it as `\\host_name_or_ip\share_name` on device.

Comment: Thanks, Norbert.  That's exactly what I tried. The web server considers them all invalid paths, however.  The web server anticipates a Windows share, I think...but there has to be a way that Samba talks to Windows, as I can map a Windows drive to a Samba share without difficulty. I have a belief, or perhaps just a faith, that Samba somehow has a translation to Windowspeak that I can use in the input field to the web server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know the IP address and netbios name of the computer, and know the shared folder path on my Ubuntu machine, but don't know how to plug that in to come up with a valid UNC path to my shared folder.

Your "shared folder path" appears to be something like `/home/dan/Public`. That is not your samba network path. Samba hides the internal file structure of your machine. I don't know how you created your share so look at the output of these commands:

```
testparm -s

net usershare info --long
```

Your share name will display surrounded by brackets --- and I'm guessing it's: `[Public]`. If this is the case your network path is:

```
\\ip-address\Public
```